# NiFi - Issue when running multiple data source ingestion pipelines concurrently

Tags: apache-nifi

When multiple flow files executed in a putSFTP processor at almost the same time, the files was placed into wrong destination.
The sftp usernames are different, and come from flow file attributes. The first flow file goes to correct destination while the other 3 files go to the sftp destination of first file.

We are using Apache NiFi 1.12.1

Comment: Set batch size to 1 if destination depends on username.

Comment: Thanks so much. It worked

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @daggett if you take a look at the [PutSFTP docs](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.15.3/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutSFTP/index.html) there is a property called `Batch Size`.

> Batch Size: The maximum number of FlowFiles to send in a single connection

If multiple FFs reach the PutSFTP at the same time, they will be batched.

Try setting this to 1 and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks so much. It worked